# Working with Bib files in Word/LibreOffice

Tags: bibtex, open-office

I've a huge database of books in `.bib` files.
Are there any ways to import this database into Microsoft Word, Open Office, Libre Office etc.?

Comment: Do you mean directly (for example http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/index.html), or by importing it into a Word-focussed tool such as Endnote? Either way, I suspect this is close to the border for 'off-topic' for us as what's primarily needed is knowledge about Word/LibreOffice rather than about the TeX side.

Comment: JabRef has a plugin for OpenOffice: http://jabref.sourceforge.net/OOPlugin-jabref.php

Comment: Actually, I need to have all latex-processing power (I use biblatex + biber + custom styles for biblatex) to be used during referencing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Bibtex4word](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/index.html) can be used with word and you can insert citations in word from `.bib` files.

I think I forgot to mention [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/features/) which offers some functionality.

[image]

*Disclaimer* I never use word, hence I don't give any assurances.

Comment: Just a note: latest update of Bibtex4word is from 2016.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is a tad old but I've just pass through this experience now and might be useful to someone.

I use [`JabRef`](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) as my Reference Manager on TeX, it does enable to export to Ms Word easily:

*File*... *Export* - Select *MS Office 2007 xml*.

It works perfectly with my MS Office 2010 and should work with recent versions too. I do recommend using `UTF8` as Database Encoding as this is what MS xml expect.

[image: JabRef exporting to word]

Inside MS Word go to the *References* tab, then click *Manage Sources*. 
[image: MS WORD references sources]

Press the *Browse...* button and select your exported file

[image: browse... button]

Comment: how do you then import into word?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG See my edit, I've added information on how to import.

Comment: Great answer. Everything worked as expected with my original bib file with no surprises.

Answer (score 6):

Zotero.org also provides bibtex plugins for Libreoffice and MS Word.

Comment: This isn't quite right.  Zotero allows import and export of Bibtex files into your Zotero database, and Zotero offers macros that allow you to insert/edit references from your Zotero database in Word and Open/Libre Office and to make reflists from them, but it is tricky to keep your Zotero and Bibtex databases in sync, because Zotero has a different internal representation of reflist items than Bibtex.  You will find yourself managing two bib databses in parallel.

Comment: [Better-Bibtex](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex) has more or less provided a very convenient solution to the sync issue.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried couple of above approaches on Mac OS. None worked. However, [steps](http://blog.pengyifan.com/using-bibtex-in-ms-word-2015-mac-os/) provided by Yifan Peng worked like a charm (took less than a min).

Here are the steps:

1. Go to following location
   ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.word/Data/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office
2. See if `Sources.xml` file exists. If so, create a back up of this file (e.g., Sources.xml.bak)
3. Use `JabRef` to export your `.bib` file to Word supported `.xml` file. Name it as `Sources.xml`.
4. Move it to the above location.
5. Restart word and start working. :-)

Comment: Any update for MS Word 16.15? There is no Sources.xml in that location, and creating one there seems to have no effect

Comment: Here's the new location:
~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office

Comment: For Word 365 on BigSur and newer ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.word/Data/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office