# How to achieve the sort and compress behavior in Bibtex4word

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, msword

I needed to work with bibtex and word, and this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88179/7561) gave me the solution: [`Bibtex4word`](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/index.html).

However, I ran into a problem. How can I achieve the sort and compress citation style that the natbib and other packages provide. What I mean with this is to have the bibliography sort by citation order, and then grouped citations being sorted by author within the group. For example, if you have a citation

```
Bla [Foo, Bar], bla [Car, Ar]
```

it should be formated as

```
Bla [1,2], bla [3,4]

[1] Bar
[2] Foo
[3] Ar
[4] Car
```

Instead I obtain

```
[1] Foo
[2] Bar
[3] Car
[4] Ar
```

My current format style is `ieeetran/ndusch`

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Bibtex4word is a pluggin for word, and I don't know if I upload a file in word to some place that would make any difference. By now, I resolve it by sorting it by hand, but who knows if there is another way. If you think that this is too narrow question, I can remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from Mike, and there is no solution, but he gave me one workaround.

> If you change your option to `ieeetrans/ndusch` and refresh the
>   bibliography then the entire bibliography will be sorted
>   alphabetically and also the entries within each cited group will be
>   re-ordered to be in alphabetical order.
>
> Then if you change the option back to  `ieeetran/ndusch` you will get
>   what you want.

I leave this here, in case someone need it someday.

Answer (score 0):

you might be interested in our tool docear4word which is an alternative to bibtex4word. is's based on the citation style language and offers a comfortable gui. although docear4word was primarily intended for docear users, it works with (almost?) any bibtex file.
http://www.docear.org/software/add-ons/docear4word/overview/